# Pytorch: how to get the tensor of neurons for each hidden layer?

Tags: python, pytorch, data-visualization, distribution, tensorboard

in a generic deep neural network's architecture you have a sequence of hidden layers connected to each other. Let's call *weights* the set of number that provide this connection between 2 different hidden layers and *neurons* the set of numbers that define one of these hidden layer.

I'd like to visualize the distribution of the **neurons** associated to each hidden layer in my deep neural network. In principle, given the tensor I can easily do it through tensorboard.
For example if I was interested in the distribution of **weight** between layers I could do something like that:

```py
for n, w in self.model.named_parameters():
    self.writer.add_histogram('Weights connection {}'.format(n), w, global_step=t)
```

where n is the name of the module, w is the corresponding tensor of weight and t is the index at which our summary is saved.

**Is there an equivalent way to iterate through hidden layers calling tensors associated with the neurons' state of each layer?**

Comment: I am not getting what is wrong with this approach.

Comment: What does a neuron's state mean? Do you mean activations for some specific input?

Comment: Hi Ivan, there is nothing wrong with this approach; I just don't know how to do the same to store the neurons state of a specific layer instead of the weights between neuron layers

Comment: Hi GoodDeeds, in a generic deep neural network's architecture you have a sequence of hidden layers connected to each other. I called weight the set of number that provide this connection between 2 different layer and neurons the set of numbers that define one of these hidden layer; thank's for the comment, I'll edit the question to be more clear. Let me know if this point is still unclear

Comment: It's still not very clear, are you referring to the _bias_ terms? If not, can you describe how the "set of numbers that define one of these hidden layer[s]" is used in the network, maybe that will make it clearer.

Comment: Conseder a 1-hidden layer perceptron as an example; in this case the input vector (for example the vector of pixel for an image dataset) is fully connected to the hidden layer. So, calling I_i the generic input component we will have, considering an N-dimensional input vector: H_j = \sum_i=1^N I_i * w_ij (where w_ij is the weight that connect the input component i to the hidden-layer component j). What I'm looking for is the set of H_j  (each element of this set is what I called neuron of the layer in the past messages)